# How to map an image of 2048 * 2048?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda

I'm doing a fractal in Cuda C and I already did my program for an image of 1024 * 1024 but I would like a larger image of 2048 * 2048, I have problems about how image mapping could help me Annex my two code the 1024 * 1024 and the What am i trying to do

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#define MAX_ITER 5000
#define N 1024
#define BLOCKS 32
#define THREAD 1
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
__global__ void mul(unsigned char *imagen){
int i=blockIdx.y*gridDim.x+blockIdx.x;
int j=threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;   
    double x,y,a,b,xnew,ynew,sq;
    double iter;
    iter=0;
        x=0;
        y=0;
        a=((3.0/(N))*j-2);
        b=((2.0/(N))*i-1);
        sq=abs(sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)));
        while((sq<2)&&(iter<MAX_ITER))
        {
            xnew=((x*x)-(y*y))+a;
            ynew=(2*x*y)+b;
    x=xnew;
            y=ynew;       
    sq=abs(sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)));
            iter=iter+1;        
        }
        if(iter==MAX_ITER)
        {
            imagen[i*(N)+j]=255;
        }
        else
        {
            imagen[i*(N)+j]=0;
        }
}
int main(){
dim3 bloques (32,32);
dim3 threads(32,32);
unsigned char *matriz_a;
unsigned char *matriz_dev_a;

matriz_a = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * N*N);
cudaMalloc((void **)&matriz_dev_a, N*N*sizeof(unsigned char));
cudaMemcpy(matriz_dev_a, matriz_a, sizeof(unsigned char) *N*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
/**************************************************************/
mul<<<bloques, threads>>>(matriz_dev_a);
cudaMemcpy(matriz_a, matriz_dev_a, sizeof(unsigned char) *N*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
/**************************************************************************/
/************************************************************************/
/***********************************************************************/
const cv::Mat img(cv::Size(N, N), CV_8U, matriz_a);
cv::namedWindow("foobar");
cv::imshow("foobar", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
free(matriz_a);
cudaFree(matriz_dev_a);
}
```

Good to do the mapping only change a few lines for example

```
#define N 2048
dim3 bloques (45,45);
mul<<<bloques, 1>>>(matriz_dev_a);
```

Think of sending a thread in each block but when running does not do anything it costs me a little to think about what the mapping might be like.
Sorry for my English
Good evening and I hope to say thank you anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with the current code.

1. The code is not scaleable as the number of blocks are fixed.
2. Incorrect indexing inside the kernel. Global index `j` does not scale with changing number of blocks.

The issues can be solved as follows:

**Make the number of blocks dynamic**, i.e. dependent on the input data size:

```
dim3 threads(32,32);
dim3 bloques;
bloques.x = (N + threads.x - 1)/threads.x;
bloques.y = (N + threads.y - 1)/threads.y;
```

**Standardize the indexing inside the kernel:**

```
int i= blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int j= blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

The modified code works fine on fractal size 2048 x 2048.

Comment: Oh thank you, I think I'm going to study more, I'll make it work
Thank you!!